# undefined method 'class' after declare routes and relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i've been starting to learn rails and ruby. Im coding and app that one user has many buys and sell. I've been doing all the tutorials and looking for many answers here in SOF but without success so this is my issue:

> NoMethodError in SellsController#create
>   undefined method `sell' for #

Where my user is "usuario" in spanish.

I know im missing something in somewhere because i already do this with the buys and works good. These are my files

**Usuario.rb (Model)**

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :sells
has_many :buys
end
```

There is the "Has_many"

**Sell.rb (Model)**

```
class Sell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  after_create :set_estado

  private

  def set_estado
    self.estado = true
  end

end
```

That method is because Im trying to set the "estado" (Status) as true.

**Sells Controller**

```
class SellsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_sell, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!

  # GET /sells
  # GET /sells.json
  def index
    @sells = Sell.all
  end

  # GET /sells/1
  # GET /sells/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /sells/new
  def new
    @sell = Sell.new
  end

  # GET /sells/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /sells
  # POST /sells.json
  def create
    @sell = current_usuario.sell.new(sell_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sell.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sell, notice: 'La venta ha sido creada con exito' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sell }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @sell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sells/1
  # PATCH/PUT /sells/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sell.update(sell_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @sell, notice: 'La venta ha sido modificada con exito.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @sell }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @sell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sells/1
  # DELETE /sells/1.json
  def destroy
    @sell.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sells_url, notice: 'La venta ha sido eliminada con exito.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_sell
      @sell = Sell.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def sell_params
      params.require(:sell).permit(:usuario_id, :fecha_compra, :peso_final, :monto, :estado, :cantidad)
    end
end
```

Im using scaffolds and the gem devise for authenticate.

I don't know what im missing because i have almost the same thing in buys and it's working but for sells doesnt work :(

My **Routes.db**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :usuarios
  devise_for :users
   resources :usuarios do
     resources :buys
     resources :sells
   end

  get 'welcome/index'
  post 'welcome/index'
  post 'users/index'
    resources :buys
    resources :users
    resources :sells

end
```

This is my first app on rails so i dont know what i missing now. Im using devise,Rails 4.2.1 and postgre as database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your association is a `has_many`, Rails will use the plural form of the model as the association name. So instead of

`current_usario.sell.new`

try:

`current_usario.sells.build`

If you only expect one `Sell` per user, use a `has_one` association instead.

P.S. You might consider using "sales" instead of "sells", and "purchases" instead of "buys".

Comment: Thanks you. That was exactly the problem . I will take that advice! i think i need improve my english :)